# blank space in a 2 column templae below a paragraph occupies whole column

Tags: two-column, paragraphs, columns

I am having following section

```
\section{How something works }

{paragraph}user uses an open source library\cite{user31} which can
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Detect unusual firewall behaviours between snapshots.
    \item Alert users to any unusual behaviours and provide a comparison with expected behaviours.
    \item Provide potential remediation steps.
\end{enumerate}
```

and then I have text after above section random paragraph

```
aaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbb
```

but there is a big big blank space in the column as below marked in red
[image: blank column]
I am not able to understand why is this big column blank is coming what should I check here?

Comment: you haven't provided anything to help anyone answer but but presumably you have `\flushbottom` in effect and the top of the right hand column has something that would not fit at the bottom of the left column.

Comment: The information you've provided so far is woefully insufficient for allowing a diagnosis, let alone for giving anyone a fighting chance to come up with a solution. Please start by providing information about the document class you employ and which packages you load. Next, do please *a lot more* information about the contents of the page that contains the unsightly gaps.

Comment: Similar comment from me as before: Why do you not provide a MWE as described in my last answer? :)

Comment: I do not know what should a Minimum Working example look like sir. I have no understanding how how latex things should be documented or working. I read many tutorials blogs but it all seems needs an expert guidance to understand them. With some one literally spoon feeding me that this means this, that means this like that thats why I am not able to explain my points clearly when I ask a question. I have made a separate word file of each question that I opened here wrote the comments or answers or links I got in that word file also noted various blogs links in it. But it all seems very

Comment: very difficult for me to understand. I have made a separate documentation of problems I am facing while writing the latex document. I wish if I can share that document with some one and get an expert comment on that. I am fiding myself in a situation if I use ms word that will be quite easy for me rather than messing up with latex, I will try for one more week and if things dont work for me I will not use latex any more.

Comment: Remark: There are Latex experts that you can hire. Look for Latex consultant.

Comment: If you don't know anything about Latex, then I would recommend to read a book from cover to cover. If you ask a low-quality question here every 5 hours, then you will probably not be successful.

Comment: I am a poor student who has a lot of academic pressure and I am trying to cope up with all the deadlines so all the questions which have been there from several months or so I ask as I get time because I do  not understand,suggest me a book for latex yesterday I downloaded and read the not so short introduction to latex
https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/
 ,https://www.quora.com/Is-LaTeX-dead-If-yes-what-are-some-modern-alternatives,https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0115069,  I wish if I could follow what ever you said.I now like latex to be honest.

Comment: It will take me a lot of time with my level of understanding and experience to write a professional quality thesis. I keep reading discussions on minimum working example
https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that
the only thing is all the links which I got in comments on tex.stackexchange.com I noted them in word file and that file has become 8 pages. Some I could understand some I could not. I unfortunately do not have the money to spend any one to teach me. Our tution fees is 1347 USD for a semester and in that